# Trying to retrieve a directory list from a NAS server in my lan

Tags: ios, swift, directory, server, nas

I am new in swift and I try to find out how to retrieve a directory list from a NAS Server into my App. The NAS Server, MAC and iPAD are in my LAN.

I searched for exactly that problem but could not find any hints and I am still working on this since days.

I tired using the NSFileManger and enumeratorAtURL but when I change the URL to the URL of the local NAS I can not retrieve any values. I always get:

*The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)*

Only accessing device directories is working.

This is the relevant code snippet I use:

```
        var fileManger = NSFileManager()
        var keys = [NSURLIsDirectoryKey]

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.178.55/photos/")!

        var handler = {
            (url:NSURL!,error:NSError!) -> Bool in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
            println(url.absoluteString)
            return true
        }

        var enumarator = fileManger.enumeratorAtURL(
            url, includingPropertiesForKeys:
            keys, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(),
            errorHandler:handler)
```

Is there any idea how I can solve this issue?

Regards
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFileManager` does not handle HTTP. It is designed to work with `file:` URLs. If your NAS is just presenting a readonly view of its filesystem via HTTP, then you'll need to use HTTP requests, primarily with [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSession). How you determine the attributes of files and directories depends on how your NAS exposes that information.

If your NAS is exposing WebDAV, then you'll need a WebDAV client. See [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) and [DAVKit](https://github.com/mattrajca/DAVKit) (which ConnectionKit uses) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. Then I will look into NSURLSession and the WebDAV client you have send. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more comment: I just found out that CFFTPStream is helping me. There is an Apple example code for doing ftp. It does what I need :) (SimpleFTPSample)